# Selenium chrome driver "headless" mode gives NoneType' object has no attribute error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape one web page using Selenium chrome driver in headless mode but it gives me error also very slow.

When I disable headless mode it works well very faster!

My code :

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import ssl
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/sarathc/Desktop/costco/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)


def listResponse(url):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
    return soup

soup = listResponse("https://www.costco.com.au/Smart-TVs-Audio-Cameras/c/cos_21")

cat =  soup.find_all("div", {"class": ["category-node ng-star-inserted"]})

for sk in cat:
    print(sk.find("a").get("href"))
```

Error :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

How i can run this code in headless mode without error and much faster like without headless mode ?

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases you need to add an User-Agent to get the page source in headless mode.

Code snippet:-

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.headless = True
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Chrome/80.0.3987.132")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=chrome_options)

def listResponse(url):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
    return soup

soup = listResponse("https://www.costco.com.au/Smart-TVs-Audio-Cameras/c/cos_21")

cat =  soup.find_all("div", {"class": ["category-node ng-star-inserted"]})

for sk in cat:
    print(sk.find("a").get("href"))
```

And also, you don't have to add `chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")` when you've already specified the window-size.

Comment: Yes it works :)